# Apply different styles in component based on body tag classes/attributes

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to get the colour of text in my component to change based on what class the body tag has on my page, but because of encapsulation (I think) using something like this doesn't work -

```css
body.pink p
{
  color: pink;
}

body.blue p
{
  color: blue;
}
```

There are dozens of posts here on SO asking how to change the body's style from inside your component, but I'm after the exact opposite.

Edit: Just to be clear, I only want the CSS to effect my component, they just need to change when `body` changes.

Comment: That would have to be on your global styles because the `body` is not inside of your component. Component styles only apply to the elements within the component.

Comment: I only want to effect elements within my own component, but I want them to change based on when `body` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following component CSS syntax appears to work:

```
body.pink :host p {
  color: pink;
}

body.blue :host p {
  color: blue;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsyhd9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.css) for a demo.